# Main menu not showing in application

Tags: android, xml

Hello guys so my problem is that the menu isn't even showing up, I tried things like: `app:showAsAction="always"` but it didn't help, then I tried changing `tools:context=".Main"`
Here's my full code:

main_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".Main">



<item
    android:id="@+id/changeCityID"
    android:title="@string/changeCity"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background= "#ff1ba1ee"
tools:context="weather.hyper.com.weather.Main">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cityText"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:text="Zagreb, HRV"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/vrijemeIcon"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cityText"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/temparaturaText"
    android:text="12°C"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cityText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:textSize="42sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/windText"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="Vjetar"
    android:layout_below="@id/vrijemeIcon"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cloudText"
    android:text="Oblaci"
    android:layout_below="@+id/windText"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tlakText"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:text="Tlak"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cloudText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/humidText"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:text="Humidity"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tlakText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/riseText"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:text="Sunrise"
    android:layout_below="@+id/humidText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/setText"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:text="Sunset"
    android:layout_below="@+id/riseText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/updateText"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:text="Zadnji update"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/setText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="weather.hyper.com.weather">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

the code looks like this

```
`package weather.hyper.com.weather;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.changeCityID:
            //
            break;
    }
    return true;
}



}`
```

Comment: read Develop>API Guides>User Interface>Menus

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you implement the methods onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected in your main activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
      case R.id.changeCityID:
        //doSomething
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing your MainActivity code. Your activity should call the main_menu.xml file. Make sure main_menu.xml is under the menu folder. Then in the activity (or your application screen) that you want this menu in, make sure you have something similar to this implemented;

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
      case R.id.changeCityID:
        // Enter what you would like to do when user clicks on menu item
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Note that you are missing the "@Override" keyword above the onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected functions. Change that and let me know.

Comment: Accept this as the answer if it fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

put this line on your onCreate(....)

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

to call the Android Menu, and implement menu method

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```